# How to copy all *.html files from one folder to another using bash script?

Tags: bash

I have following folders structure:

```
..
 documents
    folder_destination  // <- here I want to put *.html files
    project
       scripts
          myScript.sh
       folder_source
          a.html
          b.html
          c.html
```

I want to write a bash script in myScript.sh file,
which will copy all *.html files from folder_source to folder_destination.

myScript.sh  code sample:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd ../folder_source
for f in *.html
do
   cp -v "$f"  ../../folder_destination/"${f%.html}".html
done
```

But it does not work

Comment: `cp documents/project/folder_source/*.html documents/folder_destination/` ?

Comment: Can I use relative paths? @Dex' ter

Answer (score 7):

Why would you even loop through the files ?

You can simply:

```
cp -v documents/project/folder_source/*.html documents/folder_destination/
```

---

If you want to use relative paths, you can do this from `folder_source`:

```
cp -v *.html ../../folder_destination/
```

---

More, if you're on a lower level than `folder_source` you can, on the same rule as above, do the following:

```
cp -v ../*.html ../../folder_destination/
```

---

Even more, if you don't want to mess something up, just create two variables, say:

- `SOURCE_DIRECTORY` and
- `DESTINATION_DIRECTORY`,

and assign them the absolute paths for `folder_source` and `folder_destination`. That way, you can simply:

```
#!/bin/bash

SOURCE_DIRECTORY='/home/Foo/folder_source'
DESTINATION_DIRECTORY='/home/Foo/other_folder/folder_destination'

cp -v $SOURCE_DIRECTORY/*.html $DESTINATION_DIRECTORY
```

Without having to worry anymore.

---

To expand on this answer, I've also used the `*.html` [`glob`](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html) which basically means: *give me all the files which contain the `.html` termination*.

Be careful and remember that *glob* does not use the standard regular expression set.

Comment: It shows me an error: cd: ../folder_destination: No such file or directory  @Dex' ter

Comment: Check the edits for a full solution :) Tested on a CentOS 7.3 machine.

Comment: I tried this way: cp -v ../folder_source/*.html  ../../folder_destination   but get an error: ../folder_source/*.html  No such file or directory

Comment: Just run the last block of code from my answer and you should be fine

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try -

```
find /home/Foo/folder_source -name "*.html" -exec cp {} /home/Foo/other_folder/folder_destination  \;
```

Comment: I cannot use absolute paths @VIPIN KUMAR

Comment: I want to use paths related to the script folder